# SPRESENSE BLE-EVK-701 が SPRESENSE SDKで動作確認ができない

Tags: spresense, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

SPRESENSE BLE-EVK-701 を SPRESENSE SDKで動作確認が出来ませんでした。

■環境
ubuntu 18.04
VSCode V1.57.0
SPRESENSE SDK v2.2.0
ブートローダ v2.2.0

■状況
Arduino SDK 環境では、動作確認が出来ており、
AndroidのBLEスキャナーアプリ(BLE Scanner)から、
ペリフェラルアドバタイズパケットを確認、コネクション確立、送受信のサンプル動作確認済みです。

しかしながら、SPRESENSE環境下では動作の確認が出来ません。
そのため、ハードウェア起因では無いと考えております。

SPRESENSE環境下で試したことは下記です。

- SPRESNSE SDKのExampleの実行
  以下手順

1. SDKコンフィグ ー> 新規作成
2. Feature の bluetoothを選択
3. Example の ble_central, ble_peripheralを選択
4. ビルドー>書き込み
5. ble_peripheralを実行し、上記スキャナーアプリで確認
   BLUETOOTH_LE_NAMEに記述されている"SONY-BLE-CLASSIC"というデバイス名で
   スキャナーアプリから確認できるかと思いましたが、デバイスを検出出来ませんでした。

- [rohmのExample](https://github.com/RohmSemiconductor/NuttX/tree/master/examples/bluetooth)の実行
  SPRESNSE SDKのExampleの実行手順に加え、
  上記リンクのbluetooth.cを、新しいアプリケーションでコピーして実行。
  SPRESNSE SDKのExampleの実行と同様、デバイス名を確認できませんでした。

手順の誤りや、
どのような手順で実行すればよいか等ご教授願えますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Spresense SDKにある Bluetooth のドライバは、bluetooth\hal\bcm20706 を見る限り、

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/sdk/modules/bluetooth/hal/bcm20706

Cypress 社の BCM20706 のみ対応に見えますね。

https://www.digikey.jp/catalog/ja/partgroup/bcm20706/62903

なので、feature/bluetooth のコンフィグでは、SPRESENSE BLE-EVK-701 の MK71251-02A は動かないみたいです。

Rohmさんのページに NuttXのドライバもあるみたいです。

https://www.rohm.co.jp/support/spresense-add-on-board

Answer (score 0):

下記GitHubリンクにアップしているSPRESENSE BLE-EVK-701向けNuttXサンプルドライバの開発者の一人です。

[Driver and sample app, GitHub, Rohm Semiconductor](https://github.com/RohmSemiconductor/NuttX)

・上記手順を確認しましたが特に問題と思えることは見つかりませんでした。

・ハードウェアの構成について確認させてください。SPRESENSEメインボード[CXD5602PWBMAIN1]とBLEボード[SPRESENSE BLE-EVK-701]は直接コネクタ接続されているでしょうか？それとも中間にSPRESENSE拡張ボード[CXD5602PWBEXT1]を介して接続されているでしょうか？後者の場合、メインボード上でUART2をEnableするためにコネクタJP10のP1とP2をショートする必要があります。(下記Readmeに記載)こちらはいかがでしょうか？

[Readme for BT sample, GitHub, Rohm Semiconductor](https://github.com/RohmSemiconductor/NuttX/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/README.txt)

Comment: Koki-O さん、こんにちは。ご投稿ありがとうございます。こちらのご投稿は、今回の質問に答えるものという認識でよろしいでしょうか？　「こういうドライバを作っているので、これを使ったら通るかも」という趣旨のご回答でしたら、そうと分かるように [edit] いただけますと幸いです